# UICollectionView: glitches while scrolling to the last cell with animation after cell deletion

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` with its direction setting to `Horizontal`.Here I am adding some cells dynamically to the `UICollectionView`,and I hope it automatically scrolls to the last added cell with scrolling animation.Here is what I have done.

```
[self.collectionView reloadData];

[self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:self.chooseSeats.count - 1 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionRight animated:YES];
```

Adding cell's animation is perfect,but deleting them is somewhat strange.Can anyone help me?

Comment: Did you update self.chooseSeats when you delete cells?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, `UITableView` doesn't reload its underlying contents representation immediately. This causes many issues. There is a much safer way of doing what you want: [batch updates](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH10-SW9). Please try that out, I'm sure it'll help you.